# Como criar uma rota no Rails que aceite uma url com ponto (.) ? tipo "usuario@gmail.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rotas

Bom dia,

Tenho uma aplicação onde os usuários cadastram suas informações e a chave primaria de cada usuário é o seu email. Então no método *show* o parâmetro que eu recebo é o email.

No entanto, as rotas default não aceitam o que vem depois do ponto e quando tento acessar as informações de algum usuário, recebo o erro:

> Couldn't find Usuario with 'email'=usuario@gmail

e embaixo, isso:

> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"usuario@gmail", "format"=>"com"}

Eu já tentei criar rotas personalizadas mas nada funciona:

```
  match "usuarios/:email" => "usuarios#show", :via => [:get], :constraints => { :email => /.+@.+\..*/ }
```

Agradeceria muito se alguém tivesse uma sugestão do que devo fazer

Comment: tenta mudar a expressão regular para `/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i`

Comment: Deu outro erro: Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i